# Update a column, all rows

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I added a new column to my table but I forgot to add the `:default` option. Now I want to populate that column on every single row.

Is there a way to do with using the console? I've been searching google for the past hour but I can't find anything.

I know how to do it for a single object, but not for all rows of a model.

```
Foo.find(1).update_attribute(:myattribute, 'value')
```

Comment: Do you want to assign same value for every row or different for each?

Comment: The same value for all. Thanks

Comment: ok, @petrov. You can try update_all method

Answer (score 142, accepted):

Try this:

```
Foo.update_all(some_column: "bar")
```

This will generate SQL query to database:

```
UPDATE "foos" SET "some_column" = "bar";
```

Comment: Thanks you pake007. This works. Initially I tried ModelName.update but it didn't work

Comment: No problem @Petrov, and even more, you can pass a condition param to this method. like: Foo.update_all({:new_column => "bar"}, {:old_column_1 => nil}) . It will update all records that has a nil value on 'old_column_1' column.

Comment: But for rails 2.2? what syntax use?

Comment: In rails 3 and 4 this method is a member of `ActiveRecord::Relation`, thus it can be chained with `where`'s and friends, like this: `Foo.where(old_column_1: nil).update_all(new_column: 'bar')`

Answer (score 25):

Since you already created the new field in a previous migration, create a brand new migration:

```
rails g migration UpdateFoos
```

Modify the migration:

```
def self.up    
  say_with_time "Updating foos..." do
    Foo.find(:all).each do |f|
      f.update_attribute :myattribute, 'value'
    end
  end
end

# from command line
Rake db:migrate
```

Let me know if this works, it might need a few adjustments. See rails [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Migration.html) for more:

Comment: Great answer. Rails3 people, use Foo.all instead of Foo.find(:all) in the example above.

Comment: While you're right about the new migration, if you have a lot of columns :each is the slow way to update all of them. :update_all will be substantially faster.

Answer (score 3):

you can do like this:

> Foo.update_all(new_column: "bar")

Answer (score 2):

Of course you can use smth like `Foo.update_all(:myattribute => "value")`, but it'll modify only already created data. To set default value for all "future" data it's a good way to create a separate migration like this:

```
rails generate migration AddDefaultValueToFoo
```

Modify new migration (for ex. myattribute has a string type) like this:

```
class AddDefaultValueToFoo < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    change_column :foos, :myattribute, :string, :default => "value"
    Foo.update_all(:myattribute => "value")
  end
end
```