# How to update a rails table column with values based on current values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a Match model, with a field called effective_from. Every entry in this column is different. I would like to increase each entry by 10 hours e.g. + (36000). I can see [how to update_all values of a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4512696/update-a-column-all-rows), but that shows how to change all values to ***the same*** value

I have tried a few things including

```
Match.update_all(effective_from: Match.pluck(:effective_from) + 36000))
```

But I can't quite get it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resort to SQL:

```rb
Match.update_all('effective_from = effective_from + 36000')
```

Comment: I forgot to mention effective_from was character class, so I used `Match.update_all("effective_from = TO_TIMESTAMP(effective_from, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') + '10 hours'::interval;")`

Comment: @user5783745 `effective_from = effective_from::timestamptz + '10 hours'::interval` is more straightforward. Why not store `effective_from` as a `timestamptz`?